# Blender Python script bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply() works with cube but not cylinder

Tags: blender

Blender 3.5.1

I have a Blender Python script which creates a bunch of cubes with the name `main_` and a unique number suffix. After each `main_` cube is created I create a number of cylinders and  attempt to union them to the `main_` object. I then create a number of cubes and attempt to union them to the same `main_` object. Then I move onto the next `main_` cube and repeat.

If I take out the parts  where cylinders are unioned to `main_` the script works. The cubes are unioned to `main_` and the cylinders just stay as individual objects. However, if I try to union the cylinders to `main_` as well, I get the error

> DepreciationWarning: Passing in context overrides is depreciated in favor of Context.temp_override(..), calling "object.modifier_apply"

***Edit:** Despite the error, the script actually runs, albeit very slowly, after a very long pause and Blender not responding for a while. But I would like the get rid of the depreciation error if possible if anyone has any ideas.*

It appears from the line the error comes from that the issue is in:

```
bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(
    {"object": tX},
    modifier=bool.name)
```

However, I am trying to use exactly the same process for both the cylinders and the cubes to union them to the `main_` object.

Is there an obvious reason the cubes would work but the cylinders would not?

**Cylinder code:**

```
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cylinder_add()

cylinder = bpy.context.selected_objects[0]
cylinder.name = "this_node_" + str(cylinder_count)

cylinder.dimensions = (cylinder_dia, cylinder_dia, geometry_sizes["road_height"] + random_small_decimal

cylinder_location_x = float(x_nodes[x_node_count])
cylinder_location_y = float(y_nodes[y_node_count])
cylinder.location = (cylinder_location_x, cylinder_location_y, 0.0)

union_name_a = "main_" + str(area_to_export[0]) + "_" + str(area_to_export[1])
union_name_b = "this_node_" + str(cylinder_count)

context = bpy.context
scene = context.scene
tX = scene.objects.get(union_name_a)
tCut = scene.objects.get(union_name_b)
if tX and tCut:
    bool = tX.modifiers.new(name="bool_node_" + str(cylinder_count), type='BOOLEAN')
    bool.object = tCut
    bool.operation = 'UNION'
    bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(
        {"object": tX},
        modifier=bool.name)

if bpy.context.object.mode == 'EDIT':
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
# deselect all objects
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
# select the object
bpy.data.objects[union_name_b].select_set(True)
# delete all selected objects
bpy.ops.object.delete()
```

**Cube code:**

```
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()

cube = bpy.context.selected_objects[0]
cube.name = "this_edge_" + str(i)

cube.dimensions = (road_length, all_road_data[i][6], geometry_sizes["road_height"] + random_small_decimal())

cube_location_x = (max(all_road_data[i][0],all_road_data[i][3]) - min(all_road_data[i][0],all_road_data[i][3])) / 2
cube_location_x = cube_location_x + min(all_road_data[i][0],all_road_data[i][3])
cube_location_y = (max(all_road_data[i][2],all_road_data[i][5]) - min(all_road_data[i][2],all_road_data[i][5])) / 2
cube_location_y = cube_location_y + min(all_road_data[i][2],all_road_data[i][5])
cube.location = (cube_location_x, cube_location_y, 0.0)

rotation_angle = get_angle_2d(node_1[0], node_1[2], node_2[0], node_2[2])
cube.rotation_euler[2] = rotation_angle

union_name_a = "main_" + str(area_to_export[0]) + "_" + str(area_to_export[1])
union_name_b = "this_edge_" + str(i)

context = bpy.context
scene = context.scene
# main object?
tX = scene.objects.get(union_name_a)
# object to add?
tCut = scene.objects.get(union_name_b)
if tX and tCut:
    bool = tX.modifiers.new(name="bool_edge_" + str(i), type='BOOLEAN')
    bool.object = tCut
    bool.operation = 'UNION'
    bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(
        {"object": tX},
        modifier=bool.name)
                
if bpy.context.object.mode == 'EDIT':
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
# deselect all objects
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
# select the object
bpy.data.objects[union_name_b].select_set(True)
# delete all selected objects
bpy.ops.object.delete()
```